# How to index multi-dimensional array with another array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let's consider a multi-dimensional array

```
arr = np.zeros((3,2,4))
```

and some indexing array

```
index_arr = np.array([2, 1])
```

To clarify what I want to get, it's this (but I want to provide indices dynamically):

```
arr[2, 1]  # array([0., 0., 0., 0.])
```

NOT this:

```
arr[[2, 1]]  # which returns result with shape (2, 2, 4)
```

I would have liked to do something like this

```
arr[*index_arr]  # using * to unpack the items of `index_arr`
```

but that gives a syntax error. Is there a native way to do what I'm asking for?

Comment: You could do something like this `arr[np.hsplit(index_arr,2)]` (gives me  Future warning, but a array to tuple conversion should be easy)

Comment: `arr[2,1]` is equivalent to `arr[(2,1)]`.  In other words, to apply the numbers to different dimensions they need to be in a tuple,  not a list or array.  I know the array indexing documentation page is long, but you really need to take time to read it all.

Comment: @hpaulj wow... thanks